# Multi-select checkboxes with tablesorter

Tags: javascript, sorting, checkbox, html-table, multi-select

I have a Python script which generates an HTML table. The final column of the table contains checkboxes. I want to use the Shift key to select multiple checkboxes. So, I've incorporated **[this Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/659571/283650)**.

However, I'm *sorting* the table columns after loading using [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-list.html) (and after calling the above Javascript). Furthermore, the user can also sort columns by clicking on column headers. This results in the wrong checkboxes being selected after the user uses Shift-click.

So far I have tried:

- moving the *select multiple checkboxes* javascript to *after* the sorting (which seems logical to me), but then the sorting functionality does not work
- the other javascript answers to that question ([How can I shift-select multiple checkboxes like GMail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/659508/283650)) but then multi-select does not work
- other Googled code ([like this](https://gist.github.com/DelvarWorld/3784055)) - but again multi-select does not work

The code:

```
<script src='shift-click-select.js'></script>
<script src='jquery-latest.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.tablesorter.min.js'></script>
<script>
//Javascript function to sort table "my_table" by default on first column (0,0) and then on second column (1) in ascending order (0).
$(function() {
    $("#my_table").tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0],[1,0]]});
});
</script>
<table id="my_table" class="tablesorter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="%s" class="chkbox" /></td>
    ...
</table>
```

note: [shift-click-select.js is from answer mention above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/659571/283650).

My guess is that I might need to re-number the checkboxes every time the table is resorted, but I'm hoping there is an easier way?

Comment: you would need to repopulate `$chkboxes` from the "shift-code"

Comment: @Valerij: I have no idea how to do that so if you make it into a workable answer I will accept it.

Comment: put your generated code into a jsfiddle and link in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you copied the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659508/how-can-i-shift-select-multiple-checkboxes-like-gmail/659571#659571) almost exactly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastChecked = null;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $chkboxes = $('.chkbox');
        $chkboxes.click(function(e) {
            if(!lastChecked) {
                lastChecked = this;
                return;
            }

            if(e.shiftKey) {
                var start = $chkboxes.index(this);
                var end = $chkboxes.index(lastChecked);

                $chkboxes.slice(Math.min(start,end), Math.max(start,end)+ 1).attr('checked', lastChecked.checked);

            }

            lastChecked = this;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem you're probably experiencing is caused by the `var $chkboxes = $('.chkbox');` invoked on the document being ready. That's declaring a list of `.chkbox` objects in their initial order when the page loads. tablesorter then changes the order.

If what I'm assuming is correct, then getting it to work properly would be as simple as changing:

```
var $chkboxes = $('.chkbox');
$chkboxes.click(function(e) ...
```

to:

```
$('.chkbox').click(function(e) {
    var $chkboxes = $('.chkbox');
```

This way the checkbox order is determined on each click rather than once on page load.

It would help if we got to see the contents of your `shift-click-select.js`.

Comment: Ooooh, this is nice. It works! Thanks also for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

using this i was able to achieve desired function

```
$(function() {
    var $table = $('#myTable');
    var $chkboxes,lastChecked = null;
    $table
    .tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0],[1,0]]})
    .on('sortEnd',function() {
        $chkboxes = $table.find(':checkbox');
    })
    .on('click',":checkbox",function(e){
        if(!lastChecked) {
            lastChecked = this;
            return;
        }
        if(e.shiftKey) {
            var start = $chkboxes.index(this);
            var end = $chkboxes.index(lastChecked);
            var last = lastChecked.checked; //cache as we might change its value
            $chkboxes.slice(Math.min(start,end), Math.max(start,end)+ 1).prop('checked', last);
        }
        lastChecked = this;
    });
});
```

notice i [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426276/382736) `attr('checked'` to `prop('checked'` as `checked="false"` is an [invalid state](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-input-element.html#attr-input-checked)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it and it is not working... The inbetween checkboxes are not selected when I press Shift. I will do some more testing to see if I can resolve it and post back here.

Answer (score 0):

I used senordev's solution on my app, but found a large pitfall in my testing, which I've resolved below.

senordev's implied solution:

```
$('.chkbox').click(function(e) {
   var $chkboxes = $('.chkbox')

   if(!lastChecked) 
   {
      lastChecked = this;
      return;
   }

   if(e.shiftKey) 
   {
      var start = $chkboxes.index(this);
      var end = $chkboxes.index(lastChecked);

      $chkboxes.slice(Math.min(start,end), Math.max(start,end)+1).prop('checked', lastChecked.checked);
   }

   lastChecked = this;
});
```

The issue I ran into was regarding filtration, if I filtered out some rows, and shift-selected, the script would select all the hidden rows in between as well (sometimes thousands). Therefore, I added a small fix:

```
var $chkboxes = $('.chkbox')
```

to

```
var $chkboxes = $('.chkbox').filter(':visible');
```

Additional corner cases I accounted for include resetting the lastChecked value whenever the sort changes (because lastChecked might now be on a completely different page) and when the filters change (because lastChecked might not be visible anymore).

```
$("table").tablesorter({
   ...
})
// Clear the lastChecked to avoid unexpected selections.
// e.g. lastChecked might not be on the visible page anymore.
.bind("sortStart",function() { 
   lastChecked = null
}).bind("sortEnd",function() { 
   lastChecked = null
}).bind('filterEnd', function() {
   lastChecked = null
});
```