# Selecting a Range of Checkboxes in an Apex Tabular Form (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, oracle-apex

I'm trying to add the option of selecting multiple checkboxes at the same time in an apex tabular form:

I originally wanted to write some Javascript allowing to select a range of checkboxes using the intutive "standard" way of spreadsheet software to:

1. select first item
2. press & hold shift
3. select last item

But for the sake of easier implementation, I decided to just use an apex button (setting a REQUEST).
My code should select all checkboxes from the first selected to the last selected. But it simply doesn't and I can't see why.

```
var $firstChecked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').first();
var $lastChecked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').last();
$firstChecked.nextUntil($lastChecked, 'input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

I'm almost sure that I am doing something wrong with *nextUntil* because

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').prop('checked', false);
```

works just fine.

[[JSFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/W2B5U/9/) (using the copied html code from apex)

- What is wrong with my javascript code?
- Is it possible to code the
  "intuitive way" with jQuery (logging the shift key)?

Comment: `nextUntil` does not support a callback.

Comment: Here's a solution with shift: http://jsfiddle.net/W2B5U/34/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get next checkbox until last checked checkbox. But as per HTML DOM structure, all checkboxes are not siblings hence cannot use `.nextUntil()`. But they are present in each sibling trs, so find first and last trs and check the checkboxes inside tr between them.

Try this :

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    var $firstChecked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked:first').closest('tr');
    var $lastChecked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked:last').closest('tr');
    $firstChecked.nextUntil($lastChecked).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2B5U/32/)**

Comment: Thanks, didn't know nextUntil() only works for siblings.

Comment: concerning the shift+select problem: is it (theoretically) possible with jQuery?

Comment: check this, may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659508/how-can-i-shift-select-multiple-checkboxes-like-gmail

Answer (score 1):

try this :-

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
 var f=$("input[type=checkbox]").index($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').first());    
 var ls = $("input[type=checkbox]").index($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').last());
   for(var i=f;i<=ls;i++)
     {
       $("input[type=checkbox]").eq(i).prop('checked', true);
     }   
  });

  $("#myOtherButton").click(function () {
   $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').prop('checked', false);
  });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2B5U/30/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using `tr` parent of `checkbox`,

```
var start = $firstChecked.parents('tr');
var last = $lastChecked.parents('tr');

$(start).nextUntil(last).each(function(){
    $(':checkbox',this).prop('checked',true);
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2B5U/33/)