# How to select multiple check box using shift and click in angular 2

Tags: angular, checkbox, multi-select

Is there a way to select multiple checkbox based on shift and click in Angular 2. Is there any module in angular 2? Want angular 2 solution, not jquery or JavaScript solution.

Comment: You mean all boxes by shift click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I shift-select multiple checkboxes like GMail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659508/how-can-i-shift-select-multiple-checkboxes-like-gmail)

Comment: After selecting first checkbox if user clicks on another checkbox along with shift key, it should select all the checkbox in-between

Comment: And the ask is for angular 2 solution, not jquery solution.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this plunkr I altered with one way of getting the behavior you're looking for.

https://embed.plnkr.co/A8czIBHgVorKHqGRqNmk/

Basically, listen for click events, check if the shift key is held, do your checkbox logic, and then set the shiftHeld variable back to false (when a key goes up)

All of the logic is in the dashboard component and template